# Stroke order of 繡

Tags: stroke-order, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

What is the correct stroke order of 繡? Its 新字体 version 粛 is farily straightforward, but this one? Dictionaries tend to not have stroke information for the 舊字體 form.

My guess would be:

1. All the way down from the broom.
2. Cross it in the middle.
3. 片 on the left – left, top, bottom
4. Reverse 片 on the right – top, right, bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 繡 (U+7E61) is the kyūjitai form of 繍 (U+7E4D), in the same way 肅 (U+8085) is the kyūjitai form of 粛 (U+7C9B).
- The stroke order for 肅 (U+8085) is available, on [Tangorin](https://tangorin.com/kanji?search=%E8%82%85) for instance:

[image]

- For reference, the two bottom parts you're mentioning are made of 片 (U+7247) and 爿 (U+723F), but their respective stroke orders slightly differ from the ones in the combined shape, because of the presence of a large horizontal stroke in the middle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! I could have found that. It’s a strange beast. Not only it’s different from 片, but it’s even more from top to bottom than from left to right. Also thanks for the codepoints. It looks like 爿 is called しょうへん.

Answer (score 2):

I could find 嘯 which seems to have the same right part in the [YARXI dictionary](http://yarxi.ru/) (English version is called [JISHOP](http://www.jishop.com/) but has no online version):

[image]

I believe the stroke order source is [Kakijun](http://kakijun.com/). Here's its version of [肅](http://kakijun.com/c/8085.html):

[image]